# Ckeditor Dialog for building a Url from a user selected options from a JSON Dataset

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

I'm trying to use CKeditor as part of a CMS but I'm not "that" good with JavaScript and there documentation does not help much.

rather confusing could some one show me how I would change the link plugin dialog so that it shows a drop down of values and builds a URL from them, but I don't under stand how there dialog system works I have narrowed it down, i know that I will need to use the `_sources/plugins/link/dialogs/link.js` but as to how I am to a lost when working with this I just can't understand it.

Can some one show me the code i would need to add a Dropdown (select) to the dialog that has the options that then writes the value into the url Field E.G

My Server System has the URL /content/getLinks/ and this will return the CMS Pages like so,

```
[
 {"page_name":"Contact Us","url":"Contact_Us","page_id":"1"},
 {"page_name":"Welcome to Doxie Promotions","url":"Welcome_to_Doxie_Promotions","page_id":"2"},
 {"page_name":"Bands","url":"Bands","page_id":"3"},
 {"page_name":"Upcoming Events","url":"Upcoming_Events","page_id":"4"},
 {"page_name":"About","url":"About","page_id":"7"},
 {"page_name":"Lost Efftect","url":"Lost_Efftect","page_id":"10"}
]
```

Now from this data i want to build a select box like this

```
<select>
    <option value="Contact_Us:1">Contact Us</option>
    <option value="Welcome_to_Doxie_Promotions:1">Welcome to Doxie Promotions</option>
    <option value="Bands:1">Bands</option>
    <option value="Upcoming_Events:1">Upcoming Events</option>
    <option value="About:1">About</option>
    <option value="Lost_Efftect:1">Lost Efftect</option>
</select>
```

Then when one is selected I want the URL field to be changed E.G if the first was option selected the url would be

```
/content/load/pid/1/url/Contact_Us
```

I'm aware that i will need to copy the sources version of the plugin dialog over the standard one that has been min'ed

**Update what I have tried so far**
using `_sources/plugins/link/dialogs/link.js` and overwriting the `plugins/link/dialogs/link.js`

I have built this code

into the file at line 429

```
,
{
    type : 'select',
    id : 'cms_links',
    label : 'CMS Page',
    items:[],
    onLoad : function(){
        (function($){
            $.ajax({
              url: "/content/getLinks/",
              dataType: 'json',
              data: "",
              success: function(data){
                $.each(data, function(key, val){
                    $("#cms_links").append(
                        "<option value='"+val.url+":"+val.page_id+"'>"+val.page_name+"</option>"
                    );
                });
              }
            });
        })(jQuery);
    }
},
```

but there is not even a select box drawn for the code that i have added so i'm still at a loss

Comment: still reading there documentation http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.dialog.html

Still not very help full does not tell me about the values expected so far i know that i need to add some code to the file above that's just to draw the select box i'm still unsure about how i can abuse it to add values about to try hacking jQuery into it as i'm using the jQuery loaded for plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this you have to have the de-minimized version of the code this is in the _sources at path `_sources/plugins/link/dialogs/link.js` copy this over top of the minimized code at `plugins/link/dialogs/link.js` i added the code below around line 429

```
,
{
    type : 'select',
    id : 'cms_links',
    label : 'CMS Page',
    class : 'cms_links',
    items:[],
    onLoad : function(){
        (function($){
            var cms_pageSelectElement;
            var protocolSelectElement;
            var urlSelectElement;
            $.ajax({
              url: "/content/getLinks/",
              dataType: 'json',
              success: function(data){
                  $("label").each(function(){
                    var value = $(this).html();
                    if(value == "CMS Page"){
                        cms_pageSelectElement = $(".cke_dialog_ui_input_select", $(this).parent());
                        console.log(cms_pageSelectElement);
                    }
                    if(value == "Protocol"){
                        protocolSelectElement = $(".cke_dialog_ui_input_select", $(this).parent());
                        console.log(protocolSelectElement);
                    }
                    if(value == "URL"){
                        urlSelectElement = $(".cke_dialog_ui_input_text", $(this).parent());
                        console.log(urlSelectElement);
                    }
                  });

                  $(cms_pageSelectElement).append("<option selected='selected'><none CMS link></option>");
                for(var key in data){
                    var val = data[key];
                    $(cms_pageSelectElement).append(
                        "<option value='"+val.url+":"+val.page_id+"'>"+val.page_name+"</option>"
                    );
                }
                $(cms_pageSelectElement).change(function(){
                    var val = $(this).val();
                    var parts = val.split(":");
                    var url = "content/load/pid/"+parts[1]+"/url/"+parts[0];
                    $(urlSelectElement).val(url);

                });
              }
            });
        })(jQuery);
    }
},
```

you have to exploit the system slightly to update the other elements when using jQuery as there are no values you can set that are then set on to the HTML elements so you have to hack around by selecting the label then getting the input from the parent of the label

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use this plugin: http://cksource.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=18&t=24282

Comment: Spot on, helped a great deal

Answer (score 1):

I can give you this to start of: http://jsfiddle.net/VGWPL/

Comment: i'm not that bad with javascript lol, i understand what i need to do just i can't get it to draw the the element inside the dialog

Comment: And have you looked at this: http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/src/plugins_link_dialogs_link.js.html ?

Comment: yea thats what i'm working from look at my edit and see what i have done so far but it's just not working

Comment: Start around the lines 395-400. Thats where the dialog is built. After that, don't forget to edit the CSS to position and style your field.

Comment: yea that's where I am at line 429 inside the first field set tab (sort of thing) and it's still not drawing it's like CKEditor has a cache of the files but i cleared my browser cache

Comment: Apparently chrome cach is messing up i moved to Firefox and my select is there the AJAX is working just not updating the element i will look into that now thanks for you help

Comment: Ok. Just post your solution here as the answer when you finish it, please, so you can help others and satisfy our curiosity. ;)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9835/discussion-between-martin-barker-and-rcdmk)